# Array of random integers with fixed average in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random

I need to create an array of random integers which a sum of them is 1000000 and an average of these numbers is 3. The numbers in the array could be duplicated and the length of the array could be any number.

I am able to find the array of random integers which the sum of them is 1000000.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int a = 1000000;
    Random rn = new Random();
    while (a >= 1)
    {
        int answer = rn.nextInt(a) + 1;
        array.add(answer);
        a -= answer;
    }
```

However, I don't know how to find the random numbers with average of 3.

Comment: I can't understand what you are looking for, please emphasize your question

Comment: Is there a range of the random numbers? Should they all be positive? Is zero included?

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor Sorry, if the question is not explained clearly enough. Which part didn't you understand? 

Briefly, I need to generate random numbers which sum of them is     1000 000 and average of them (sum of them divided the number of them ) is 3.

Comment: @Bohemian, they should be all positive.

Comment: If the sum is 1000000, and the average must be three, then your array must have 333333 elements (not exact, but as close as you can get).

Answer (score 4):

that's mathematically not possible:

you are looking for n values, sum of which makes 1000000, and the average of them is 3, which is 1000000/n. since n can only take integer values it is not possible.

Comment: if we think that n equals 333333, and all of them is 3 except one of them is 4, sum would be 1000000. 

int a = 1000000 / n is 3 in java.

Comment: But their real average would be 3.000003000003.

Answer (score 1):

If they are constrained to an average and random, they must be constrained to a value range. A range of 1 to 5 (median is 3) seems reasonable. Also reasonable is a smooth distribution, which gives a known total and average.

This simple code will do all that:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(333334); // 1000000 / 3
// one instance of 5 must be omitted to make total exactly 1000000
numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
for (int i = 0; i < 333330; i++)
    numbers.add((i % 5) + 1); // add 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,etc
Collections.shuffle(numbers);

// Check sum is correct
numbers.stream().reduce((a,b) -> a + b).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1000000
```

---

Note that it is mathematically impossible for the average to be *exactly* `3` when the total is `1000000` (because `1000000/3` has a remainder of `1/3`), however this code gets pretty close:

```
1000000/333334 => 2.999994
```

Answer (score 0):

I would transverse the list twice, and IF the integers at these two positions added together and divded by 2 == 3 then return, else, increment your integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to write a simple average function like:

```
public double average(ArrayList<Integer> array){

    long sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer item : array){
        sum += item;
        count++;
    }
    return sum/count;
}
```

Then use it in your code like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int a = 1000000;
Random rn = new Random();
boolean isDone = true;
while (a >= 1)
{
    int answer = rn.nextInt(a) + 1;
    array.add(answer);
    a -= answer;
    if (average(array) % 3 != 0){
       isDone = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

The idea is each time we adding a new number to the array, we checking that the average can be divide with 3, if not, we getting out of the while loop.

To let us know if the algorithm went well, we need to check `isDone` variable at the end.

**And the more efficient way is:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int a = 1000000;
Random rn = new Random();
boolean isDone = true;
long sum = 0;
while (a >= 1)
{
    int answer = rn.nextInt(a) + 1;
    array.add(answer);
    a -= answer;
    sum += answer;
    if ((sum/array.size()) % 3 != 0){
       isDone = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how this works to your answer?

Comment: Yes, each time we adding a new number to the array, we checking that the average can be divide with 3, if not, we getting out of the while loop

Comment: Add that _to your answer_. And please explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

As Göker Gümüş said it is mathematically impossible to have the average be exactly 3 and the sum be a million.

The average = sum / number of elements. 
This means that number of elements = sum / average.

In this case it would need 1000000 / 3 =  333333.(3) elements. Since you can't have a third of an element with value 3 it means your average or your sum will need to be slightly off your target for it to match up.
The less notable needed difference would definitely be the average as it would only need to be a millionth of a unit off, i.e 3.000001 for you to be able to have 333333 elements summing to 1000000

Answer (score 0):

there are many answers to this question but lets say we want our random number to be 10 max (which we can change). I guess this would give a satisfactory answer.

```
import java.util.Random;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RandomSumAverage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    double sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int k = 1;
    while (sum < 1000000) {
        avg = sum / k;
        if (avg < 3) {
            int element = random.nextInt(10)+1;
            sum += element;
            arr.add(element);
            k++;
        } else {
            int element = random.nextInt(3)+1;
            sum += element;
            arr.add(element);
            k++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arr);
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

}